# How to display progress of uploading image in notification bar in android

Tags: android, notifications, image-uploading, progress

I want to display progress in notification bar in android while image is uploading and when I click on that I want to show dialog box having same value of progress as in notification bar.

I also want to cancel that uploading request.

Can you please suggest me example or library with which I can do that?

All your answer is valuable for me.

Answer (score 3):

Try this. It seems to suit your needs.
https://github.com/gotev/android-upload-service